# How to create apk from appium automation

Tags: android, android-studio, appium

I am trying to do appium automation and i had written the appium automation code. i had used appium server and my code is mention below :

```
 public class WaitTests {

     WebDriver driver;

     @Before
     public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

      capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "XT1562");

      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");

      capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");

      capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

      capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");

      capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

      driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


     }

     @Test
     public void testFirstCalculator() {

      driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button")).get(0).click();

      driver.findElement(By.name("7")).click();

     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    }
```

I want to run the code without IDE after creating .apk so what should i do to achieve. please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem and could fix it by creating a new Java module in Android Studio, adding a new gradle task in my `build.gradle` file:

```
task(runAppium, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.mypackage.appium.Appium'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

and then launching it with:

```
gradle runAppium
```

As it's a Java module you'll need to have a `public static void main(String[] args)` function which will launch the test.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in andriod studio there is Java Library type of module. So is correct to add that Java Libaray? or should I add any other module? what is runAppium and classpath inside task? can you please give us any working example?